# can't display images from localhost dev server in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I'm trying to render images in react native from my local dev server, but I'm not able to shoe images. The image URI I'm getting from the server is a proper one I checked that with copying and pasting it to the chrome tab and it opens up with a new tab showing the image.
`http://localhost:4001/f931a2c2-4268-4bd8-8f6f-c0bab923a374.jpeg`, this is the example of the URI, and this is my image component code.

```js
export const LogoImage: React.FC = ({ logo }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: "http://localhost:4001/${logo}",
        }}
        style={styles.image}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    resizeMode: "cover",
  },
  wrapper: {
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  },
});
```

Any idea and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an emulator or are you using a real device to test this out with?

Comment: @VtoCorleone I'm using my phone actually, a real android device. I should mention that I have tried it and external image link from pixabay and it worked and I believe that the problem is connecting to the localhost

Comment: You can use adb to bridge the tcp connection for that port. Otherwise localhost refers to your phone's network, not your computer's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the keyword `localhost` with you own IPv4-address. You can get it by executing `ipconfig` in cmd. I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device).

Comment: Will this work when the app is published and running on various devices?